# Get DefaultSharedPreferences in Widget?

Tags: android, widget, android-context

I need to get Boolean from `SharedPreferences` in my widget activity. How can I do that? Is that even possible? Because Widget Receiver is subclass of Broadcast receiver which is not a context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nearly all methods of the `AppWidgetProviderClass` get a `Context`, let's have a look:

```
onAppWidgetOptionsChanged (Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int appWidgetId, Bundle newOptions)
onDeleted(Context context, int[] appWidgetIds)
onDisabled(Context context)
onEnabled(Context context)
onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
onUpdate (Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds)
```

So, just use this context and you're good to go:

```
SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to obtain the SharedPreferences instance from the context, which is provided in the onUpdate() method in the widget provider. Something like this:

```
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
 SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,0);
}
```

You can store and load boolean from shared preferences with putBoolean(key, value) and getBoolean(key, value) respectively.